# JTable: how to get updated column and rows of the table?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How to get updated column and rows of a `JTable`?

For example after increasing the table columns and rows in GUI with button, I can't get the current number of column and rows after increase.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If your model class extends from [AbstractTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html), then you can fire the according event of the model implemented by the base class.

You can find the tutorial here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#fire